Shapley, cooperative games and linearity
Shapley values grant that the additivity property hold. However, I am in understanding cases where additivity in cooperative games does not hold. Specifically, I am looking for a practical example of two cooperative games defined by characteristic functions $v$ and $g$ where for a coalition $Q$, the following inequality holds:
$$(v + g)(Q) \neq v(Q) + g(Q)$$
Could you provide a concrete example of such cooperative games? I would appreciate a detailed description of the characteristic functions $v$ and $g$, and how the values of the coalitions are calculated to show that additivity does not occur.
Thank you in advance for your help!

How is the game $v+g$ defined?

It should be easy to find examples in standard sources, because there are plenty. To convey the idea: Imagine two projects which require different but partially overlapping resources. Then the value of a shared resource in the combined project will be different from just the sum of its values in the two stand-alone projects.

@BenReiniger all that we know is that $v(\emptyset)=0 $ and $v(A+B) \geq v(A)+v(B)$ (the same for $g$). You can find better info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley_value

@gg can you explain it in a more formal way?

But $v(A+B)$ (did you mean $v(A\cup B)$?) doesn't appear in your inequality, $(v+g)(Q)$ does. I think perhaps you're mixing up the game characteristic functions and the Shapley values thereof in the question?

@BenReiniger (yes is $\cup$). Yes. I would an example of a game which does not respect this property.

I'm back to my original question: how do you define the game $v+g$? (I would've guessed by the equality version of what you seek an exception to.)

you can find here in section "solution concepts" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_game_theory I would a game where the addivity property is not hold.

Ah, so I was right, the definition of $(v+w)(Q)$ is $v(Q)+w(Q)$; from that section under Additivity, "Mathematically, if $v$ and $\omega$ are games, the game $(v+\omega)$ simply assigns to any coalition the sum of the payoffs the coalition would get in the two individual games."  What you mean to ask about is a solution concept where Additivity fails?
